Sad 70's "Wa-wa" electric guitar riff - What is it called?
The sound effect I am alluding to occurs near the end of the Stairway to Heaven guitar solo: 

 at timestamp 6:25; and also in the closing scene to the Rocky Horror Picture Show: 

 at timestamp 0:19. However, I'm not sure what it would be called.

Those are just notes. Not an effect, just an interval. It’s definitely not wah wah, which is a specific effect. Wah wah is prominent in the intro to “Voodoo Child, Slight Return” by Jimi Hendrix.

I can hear slides in both places

To expand on what Todd says: ‘wah-wah’ (like most effects) changes the tone of the note (emphasising a dynamically-changing frequency range) — but in those examples only the pitch changes over time (probably by playing one note, then sliding down the string to the next).  However, in addition to other effects, I think there's a little reverb, which may enhance the effect of the slide (by smearing out the pitches a little).

I have the feeling that OP isn't aware that "effect" covers only signal processing and not playing techniques.

You will also find some examples if you listen to early Pink Floyd.  The slide is the key to the sound.

It is not a wah wah in either case. The descending pitches in both cases may fool you into thinking it is. They also account for what you hear as a “sad” sound although that is a subjective observation.
Both were done using a slide. In “Stairway” the pattern is C to B then C to A repeated 4 times. Only the C’s are plucked then sustained into the lower notes. In “Rocky Horror” it is C to A then C to G# but each note is individually plucked giving it a different character. Except for the double plucking on Rocky Horror the second part of Stairway uses the same notes as the first part of Rocky Horror which makes them sound similar to each other.

Certainly not wah wah. Just slide down, with a certain amount of distortion. Could be a let (bend) down, where the string is 'pre-bent', then allowed to return to the original fretted note. Or, unlikely, use of an actual slide, playing the higher note, sliding down to the next.
Funnily enough, both examples seem dead ringers for each other!

It sounds to me like the pitch is changing smoothly (not jumping between semitones), with no loss of tone, so it doesn't sound like a normal finger slide down a fretted fingerboard.  As you say, it could be releasing a bent string — though the second slide in Rocky Horror covers 4 semitones, which seems quite a lot to bend (especially as there's less than a second to find it after the previous note, yet it starts at the right pitch).  So an actual glass/metal slide seems most likely to me.

Your examples in the recordings are not wa wa, specifically not "wah-wah" effect pedal that is famously used on electric guitar.
An example of wah-wah pedal on electric guitar is Voodoo Child by Jimi Hendrix (among many, many other possible examples)



The effect is used right at the opening in both the rhythm and lead guitar parts.
The effect, at least its original form, is a box with a foot pedal on top which sort of resembles the gas pedal of a car. When you push the pedal up and down with your foot it applies a tone filter to the guitar sound. If the foot motion is fairly quick, it pass through dark to bright tones quickly and sounds a bit like an exaggerated spoken "wah" which is kind of dark toned with the "woo-" sound then becoming bright tones with the ending "-ah" sound.
The examples in the recordings you linked are not the wah-wah effect but are a sliding down of pitch.
I think the commonality that overlaps these two ideas - wah-wah and pitch slide - are the continuous nature of the change. One is a continuous change in tone, the other a continuous change in pitch. I supposed both could be called "sliding." Sliding tone, sliding pitch. (In the wiki article linked above note the comparison between wah-wah and expressive trumpet mutes.)
Sliding or wavering can be used in music for expressive effect. One of the most important expressive effects is vibrato which is a minute, continuous wavering of pitch. There is some overlap between the continuous nature of wah-wah, pitch slide, and vibrato, and I think it is reasonable to view that overlap as one source of the expression you feel in your examples.
However, you should also consider some other musical factors in the examples when you get to the specific feeling of "sad." The harmony in both examples touches upon minor harmonies, and there is a very broad association between minor harmony and sadness. It's not a one to one connection, but probably best described as something like a potential association.
So, I would say you are hearing expressive pitch slides used in a minor harmony context which could be perceived as sad. Personally, I think the Stairway to Heaven example might be called "melodramatic" and the Rocky Horror Picture Show example "sad" or "tragic."
